# Can't connect to MySQL server(Connection refused) , trying to install connection between Django and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to install connection between MySQL and Django, as far as the old method is only applicable to 2.x python, I use Python 3.4 and mysql.connector.django module https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html

Also following example from here http://aarvik.dk/how-to-get-started-with-django-on-top-of-python-3-4-mysql-mariadb-5-5/( MySQL Engine section)

I am getting error after commands below

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on '127.0.0.1:8000' (61 Connection refused)

```
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py runserver 8000
```

Settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'closerdb',
        'HOSTNAME': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'8000',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'closerdbpassword',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Having changed the port, I get the same error

```
 mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (61 Connection refused)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Change `ENGINE` setting to `django.db.backends.mysql `

Comment: @karthikr Error was: No module named 'django.db.backends.mysql

Comment: something weird is going on, because that is a django framework built in. Try reinstalling django in the virtualenv

Comment: @karthikr why then 'mysql.connector.django' is in the documentation ?

Comment: What are you talking about ? `django.db.backends.mysql` should *not* have thrown the error you claim it is throwing. Which indicates something wrong with the django installation.

Comment: Did you check if mysql is actuallly running?

Answer (score 2):

The default port for MySQL is `3306`.

Your Django app is running on port `8000`, change that value in your DB config.

It should look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'closerdb',
        'HOSTNAME': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'closerdbpassword',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: done. maybe I made some stupid mistake with MySQL, missed any operations I must have done?

Comment: @Vinand Follow comments: check MySQL is up and running, check your user and password for DB, check the Django's MySQL connector.

Comment: I also have MAMP installed for php, is it possible there is a conflict between MAMP and MySQL?

Comment: No, but make sure the service for MySQL in your mamp app is running, also try with this engine connector: `django.db.backends.mysql`